# Can I efficiently find the divisors nearest to the square-root?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, primorial

Suppose, I have a positive integer $\ N\ $ with many divisors , like a primorial or a factorial. The prime factorization of $\ N\ $ is known.

> Can I efficiently (without enumerating the divisors) find the divisors nearest to the square root , in other words the positive integers $\ a,b\ $ with $\ ab=N\ $ such that $\ d:=|a-b|\ $ is as small as possible ?

I tried to cosnsider the equation $\ x(x+d)=N\ $ which can only have an integer solution if $\ d^2+4N\ $ is a perfect square. But solving $\ e^2=d^2+4N\ $ would again require the factors of $\ N\ $. Any ideas ?

Comment: If you really have _many_ divisors, Fermat's factorisation method for $N$ (if $N \not\equiv 2 \pmod{4}$) or $4N$ should be rather quick. It _is_ quick if there are divisors within a few $\sqrt[4]{N}$ of $\sqrt{N}$. But I guess not all your $N$ are that nice. Nevertheless, it's probably not a bad idea to start with a bit of Fermat.